# Copying multiple columns using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to copy multiple different columns from excel spread sheet using range.

```
Committs.Range("A"&i,"C"&i).Copy                
wb3ss1.Range("A" & count,"C" & count).PasteSpecial
```

I want all the rows in column A and column C but even column B rows are copied. How to copy only A and C columns?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376995/exclude-some-columns-while-copying-one-row-to-other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just do each column individually?

```
Dim col As Variant

For Each col In Array("A", "C")
    Committs.Range(col & "1:" & col & count).Copy                
    wb3ss1.Range(col & "1:" & col & count).PasteSpecial
Next
```

Comment: I want all the rows in the columns A,C
My actual code is 
`For i=2 To countofrows1
If Committs.Cells(i,2).Value <> "" And Committs.Cells(i,10).Value<>"" then
count=count+1
Committs.Range("A"&i,"C"&i).Copy                
wb3ss1.Range("A" & count,"C" & count).PasteSpecial
End If`
@Bond

Comment: This does copy all the rows -- from row 1 to row `count`.

Comment: sorry my naming convention is little bit confusing,Here count doesn't mean the row count. If the condition is satisfied I am copying in the different spreadsheet so I am maintaining a counter for it.@Bond

Comment: Well you can copy the whole column, if you want (`Range("A:A")`) or you can use a variable like I've shown above to copy only a certain number of rows. Is `i` the row count?