# Value of Union of Ranges failing to be assigned for non-contiguous data column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am trying to assign cells `A13:E300` of one sheet to another sheet, omitting column D.

The following code fails to copy column `E`; there appears to be a problem with the `Union` function, because instead of that column's values I am getting `#N/A` assigned into that column on the hidden sheet. What is wrong?

```
Private Sub AddTemplate_Click()
 Dim Exposed_sheet As Worksheet, Hidden_sheet As Worksheet, MyPassword As String

 Set Exposed_sheet = Sheets("Exposed Sheet")
 Set Hidden_sheet = Sheets("Hidden")

  MyPassword = "string"
  'Reference: carriage return in msgbox http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=41581
  If InputBox("Please enter the password to continue." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
   & "Note: The string you type will be exposed, i.e. not '***'." & vbNewLine _
   & "Note: This will save the Excel file!", "Enter Password: Enter the correct string.") <> MyPassword Then
     Exit Sub
  End If

 ' Reference: .Protect -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746478/excel-macro-run-time-error-1004
  Hidden_sheet.Unprotect MyPassword

 'References:
 ' dynamic referencing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45889866/how-to-assign-values-from-one-sheet-into-hidden-sheet-using-excel-vba-and-skip/45889960#45889960
 ' adding text:         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612415/adding-text-to-a-cell-in-excel-using-vba
 ' Union to exclude column: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376995/exclude-some-columns-while-copying-one-row-to-other
 With Hidden_sheet
    .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 3).Resize(UBound(Exposed_sheet.Range("B6", "D9").Value, 1), UBound(Exposed_sheet.Range("B6", "D9").Value, 2)).Value = Exposed_sheet.Range("B6", "D9").Value
    .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 6).Value = "Volume/Protocol"
    .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(6, 3).Resize( _
     UBound(Union(Exposed_sheet.Range("A13:C300"), Exposed_sheet.Range("E13:E300")).Value, 1), 4).Value = _
                                      Union(Exposed_sheet.Range("A13:C300"), Exposed_sheet.Range("E13:E300")).Value
    ' If you change the order putting this prior, you must change the offsets or the cell they count from. -- DB, Aug 28 2017
    .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 3).Resize(1, 3).Merge
    .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 3).Value = Exposed_sheet.Range("A1").Value
 End With

 Hidden_sheet.Protect MyPassword

 ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

By the way, I am also interested in more flexible code: It need not be 300: Only needed until the last row with data -- data sets are separated by blank rows. Altogether should be less than 150 rows)

Comment: Your `Union(Exposed_sheet.Range("A13:C300"), Exposed_sheet.Range("E13:E300")).Value` is two `Areas` - the first area (which is used by default) is only three columns wide, but you are writing to a range that is four columns wide (i.e. `UBound(Union(Exposed_sheet.Range("A13:C300"), Exposed_sheet.Range("E13:E300")).Value, 2)` would return 3, but you hardcode 4), thus the fourth column is filled with `#N/A`s.

Comment: @YowE3K To be exact: `Union()` is a range (and ranges can be non-contiguous). While `.Value` always is either a direct value or an array of values. And arrays cannot be non-contiguous in any way (at least not in vba)

Comment: Thank you -- I was just coming to comment that, based on documentation, I have concluded that a Range and an array are different object types and so require different methods. Specifically, UBound returns the subscript of an array whereas Union returns a Range object. (Apparently Areas are subsets of (constituents of) a Range object.) However, what method should I use to accomplish this goal of essentially grabbing a Range, stripping a column to collapse the data to be assigned to another Range? Previously I stored the Range as an array, but was hoping to spare memory and expedite the module.

Comment: One solution is to assign that non-contiguous Range (E) separately, but I am hopeful for a more elegant way to assign a range that omits empty columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Range and an array are different object types and so require different methods. Specifically, UBound returns the subscript of an array whereas Union returns a Range object. (Apparently Areas are subsets of (constituents of) a Range object.)

According to [Dirk Reichel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5461205/dirk-reichel),

> **Union()** is a range (and ranges can be non-contiguous)[, whereas] **.Value** [is] either a direct value or an array of values. [A]rrays cannot be non-contiguous[.]

One solution is to assign that non-contiguous Range (E) separately.